# MySQL 3 linked tables ... find Users NOT in a specific GROUP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find all Users that are not in one specific group.
How can I find them?

```
GROUPS
|id| name      |
----------------
|1|  Koalas    | 
|2|  Grizzlies  | 
|3|  Hornets    |
----------------

USERS
|id| firstName | 
----------------
|1|    Bob     |  
|2|    Hans    |  
|3|    Jerome  |  
|4|    Katy    |  
----------------

GROUP_USER
|id| group_id  | user_id  |
--------------------------
|1|  1         |  2
|2|  1         |  4
|3|  2         |  1
|4|  2         |  2
|5|  3         |  3
|6|  3         |  4
----------------
```

How can I find the Users that are for example NOT in group 1.

Should result in

```
 |1|    Bob     |  
 |2|    Jerome  |
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using left joins:-

```
SELECT *
FROM users a
LEFT OUTER JOIN group_user b ON a.id = b.user_id AND b.group_id = 1
WHERE b.group_id IS NULL
```

Comment: gives me duplicate results :( ... with GROUP BY a.id I get all users as result

Comment: Oops, need to put the check for the group in the first LEFT OUTER JOIN, otherwise is was getting a matching row which wasn't required.

Comment: No, no DISTINCT required. The duplicates were the result of a bug in the original SQL which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

First get the user_id which are there in  `group_id = 1` from the table `GROUP_USER`.

And then find the name from `USERS` table which the ids are not there in the subquery result.

**Query**

```
select firstName
from USERS
where id not in
(
    select user_id
    from GROUP_USER
    where group_id = 1
);
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff43/1)

Comment: (I upvoted - it's a valid answer), but this will be less efficient than using the LEFT JOIN method.

Comment: I upvoted as well. It is a valid way to do it. While less efficient, the difference with small amounts of data will be minimal and less experienced coders tend to find this easier to understand. But it will probably appear in the slow query log and that would bug me a bit!